# Custom component binding: No value accessor for ''

Tags: angular

I updated my form with a custom element to `@angular/forms` as of RC2. When I perform an input binding on it using `[(ngModel)]="myModel"`, I get `No value accessor for ''` from angular and the form fails to load. The error only occurs with input binding.

Here's a plunker illustrating the issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/wxMsGuxr3GHMwNNoczT7?p=preview

The value accessor is generally working (and the model did with the old forms stuff in RC1) because the `FormBuilder` has an initial value which is correctly set through the accessor interface.

The issue seems similar to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7518 but the form directives are provided in the bootstrap code:

```
provideForms(),
{
    provide: PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES,
    useValue: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    multi: true
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `disableDeprecatedForms()` in the call to bootstrap. See here: https://plnkr.co/edit/tk1rWdmXB7umkGPYK4Ho?p=preview

Comment: Thanks but can you elaborate as to why this fixes it? It should be possible to mix old and new forms API in one project and `disableDeprecatedForms` should only suppress the warning at startup, shouldn't it?

Comment: I think it's still possible to use at least some of the old directives, but I guess the deprecated forms don't know about the new ones and they conflict somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem yesterday and this solution didn't solved it at first.
To make it work, I had to clear my browser cache.