# FormControl in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I asked the question: [Analogue of Angular 2 Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138584/analogue-of-angular-2-provider/38138620)

But after update angular to rc.4 and @angular/forms to 0.2.0 it doesn't work anymore.

Part of template:

```html
    <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
        ...
        <checkbox-view  [formControl]="formGroup.find('rememberMe')">Remember me?</checkbox-view>
    </form>
```

In component:

```js
this.formGroup = this._fromBuilder.group({
     ...
     rememberMe: [this.model.rememberMe]
});
```

And the error:
**No value accessor for ''**

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37895474/custom-component-binding-no-value-accessor-for

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I changed NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR on PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES but it's not helped

Comment: What about `disableDeprecatedForms()`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have it

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have an error only on custom component. Other inputs were working fine

Comment: No idea. Maybe a Plunker to reproduce might help.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks. While doing plunker found a bug =)

Comment: @Illorian can you please share this bug with us if it fixed your issue?

Comment: @dibs I use structure like useExisting: forwardRef(() => CheckboxComponent

That's wrong. You should need use useExisting: CheckboxComponent

That's all

Comment: Illorian, I am thinking on to start a bounty on your question, but I will do it only if you are still here and you would also accept the winner answer. What about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property controls has inside a map with all the controls.

You can just do this:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    ...
    <checkbox-view  [formControl]="formGroup.controls['rememberMe']">Remember me?</checkbox-view>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Try using formControlName without the square brackets instead of formControl.

    <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
        ...
        <checkbox-view  formControlName="rememberMe">Remember me?  </checkbox-view>
    </form>

   If you have nested fields you can also do this..

    <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
        ...
       <div formGroupName="topFieldName">
        <checkbox-view  formControlName="subFieldName">Remember me?  </checkbox-view>
       </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: There was other problem. You could read comments of question =)

Answer (score 0):

In latest angular 2 version

```
<form [formGroup]="formName">
   <checkbox-view  formControlName="rememberMe">Remember me</checkbox-view>
</form>


this.formName = this._fromBuilder.group({
     rememberMe: [this.model.rememberMe]
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.