# ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No value accessor for '' - angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Hi I am using angular2 rc4 and using ng2-my-datepicker for calendar, I have configured that module in my pack. I am facing the following error:

ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No value accessor for ''

Can Someone help me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37895474/custom-component-binding-no-value-accessor-for

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception while trying to use checkbox and radio-button elements of [PrimeNG](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/checkbox) collection of UI elements for Angular2.

The problem was appearing because I wasn't using the latest version of **primeng** node package. I was using Angular2 rc4 and there was something new in that release that broke things. They fixed that broken thing in the next version of **primeng**. After I updated the package my problem disappeared.

To see if the package has updates available run the following command: `npm outdated <package name>`